# A-FRAME Different Components Are Being Called At The Same Time

Tags: javascript, components, click, aframe

I have successfully implemented the ability to click on different markers and make their object scale or rotate every time you click on them.

My problem is, when I have two different markers with two different components they are both being called on each click. It baffles me. Why would they both be being called?

**UPDATE!!!**

I have not fixed the problem but I have narrowed down to what I believe is causing it.

I have multiple markers printed out and hanging around my office. When I focus my camera on the different markers they are basically centered on my screen. If I center the marker on my camera, both markers are on the same spot. And, they both fire.

If I have print outs of two markers side by side and both are on my screen at the same time then if I click one they click independently of each other.

If I use my hands to move the print outs and lay one marker on top of the other. Then they go back to both firing at the same time.

It definitely has something to do with the area of the screen the marker take up.

I hope that makes sense.

Is there a way to "clear" or "refresh" things when a marker is found and lost?

Ultimate goal is to have a user walk down a hallway with barcodes on the wall so that they can see virtual paintings. The user is definitely going to focus in on the barcode, so the above issue is going to be present.

Any advice is appreciated!

Here is my JavaScript code:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('marker-image-click', {
        init: function() {
          
          const objImageImage = document.querySelector('#image-image');
          let intRotationX = objImageImage.getAttribute('rotation').x;
          let intRotationY = objImageImage.getAttribute('rotation').y;
          let intRotationZ = objImageImage.getAttribute('rotation').z;

          objImageImage.addEventListener('click', function(ev, target) {
            
            if (objImageImage.object3D.visible === true) {
            
              console.log('click-image');

              objImageImage.setAttribute('rotation', {x: intRotationX, y: intRotationY, z: intRotationZ});

              intRotationX += 6.0;
              intRotationY += 6.0;
              intRotationZ += 6.0;
              
            }
            
          });
          
        }
        
      });
      
      AFRAME.registerComponent('marker-avocado-click', {
        init: function() {
          
          const objEntityAvocado = document.querySelector('#entity-avocado');
          let intScaleX = objEntityAvocado.getAttribute('scale').x;
          let intScaleY = objEntityAvocado.getAttribute('scale').y;
          let intScaleZ = objEntityAvocado.getAttribute('scale').z;

          objEntityAvocado.addEventListener('click', function(ev, target) {
            
            if (objEntityAvocado.object3D.visible === true) {
            
              console.log('click-avocado');

              objEntityAvocado.setAttribute('scale', {x: intScaleX, y: intScaleY, z: intScaleZ});

              intScaleX += 0.25;
              intScaleY += 0.25;
              intScaleZ += 0.25;
              
            }
            
          });
          
        }
        
      });
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
<a-marker marker-image-lostfound marker-image-click id="marker-image" type="barcode" value="2" emitevents="true">
        <a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" 
                  raycaster="objects: .clickable-image; useWorldCoordinates: true;"> <!-- must add this for clicking -->
        <a-image id="image-image" class="clickable-image"
                 src="images/test.png" 
                 position="0 0 0" rotation="-90 0 0" scale="1 1 1" 
                 width="" height="" opacity="1"> <!-- note the class="clickable" for clicking -->
        </a-image>
      </a-marker>
      
      <a-marker marker-avocado-lostfound marker-avocado-click id="marker-avocado" type="barcode" value="3" emitevents="true">
        <a-entity cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" 
                  raycaster="objects: .clickable-avocado; useWorldCoordinates: true;"> <!-- must add this for clicking -->
        </a-entity>
        <a-entity id="entity-avocado" class="clickable-avocado"
                  gltf-model="models/Avocado/Avocado.gltf"
                  position="0 0 0.3" rotation="-90 0 0" scale="10 10 10"> <!-- note the class="clickable" for clicking -->
        </a-entity>
      </a-marker>
```